# Change color of output in powershell

Tags: powershell, colors, output

Trying to see if it is possible to change the color of the output with the below lines. Note that this is not the complete code and only part of it:

```
$ADInfo `
    | Format-List `
        @{ Name = "Full Name"; Expression = { $_.name } },
        @{ Name = "Display Name"; Expression = { $_.displayname } },
        @{ Name = "User ID"; Expression = { $_.samaccountname } },
        @{ Name = "Email"; Expression = { $_.mail } },
        @{ Name = "Exchange Version"; Expression = { $_.msExchVersion } },
```

If possible, I would like to change the color of the name and the output independently of each other.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Combinations of `write-host -NoNewLine` could help with this. Potentially with complicated logic. What are your colouring conditions?

Comment: Do you want to [colour each row](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406264.aspx)? Certain elements? A whole column? Would be nice to know which one.

Comment: Sorry, you do sort of have your conditions. To be sure can you make a facsimile of your output for an example?

Comment: Like @Matt said, this can be done with Write-Host and the -NoNewLine parameter. Check out my answer in [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186991/its-possible-to-color-hashtable-column-in-powershell/25188478#25188478) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: @Matt I added a screenshot of the output for that. I wanted to try and change the color of either column independently, if possible. So maybe change the color of the word 'Email' and the output next to it, 'sstudent' be a different color. Hope that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

```powershell
Function Write-HostColoured{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $Input,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ColouredProperty,
        [System.ConsoleColor]$Colour = "Red"

    )

    # Get all the note properties of the object which we need for output and determining conditional formatting.
    $properties = $input | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

    # Find the property with the longest length. Used for aligning output. 
    $longestProperty = $properties | ForEach-Object{$_.Length} | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

    # Check if the property to colour requested is in $properties
    If($properties -notcontains $ColouredProperty){Write-Warning "Input object does not contain the property $ColouredProperty"}

    # Insert Line break between objects. 
    Write-Host

    ForEach($singleObject in $Input){
        $properties | ForEach-Object{
            Write-Host ("{0,-$longestProperty} : " -f $_) -NoNewline

            # Check if the property requires a colour formatting
            If($_ -eq $ColouredProperty){
                Write-Host $singleObject.$_ -ForegroundColor $Colour
            } Else {
                Write-Host $singleObject.$_
            }
        }

        # Insert Line break between objects. 
        Write-Host
    }
}

Import-Csv C:\temp\data.csv -header "Col123fff1","cl2","col3","col4" | Write-HostColoured -ColouredProperty Col3
```

## Sample Output

[image]

**Explanation**

Think this will need to evolve based on your comment but lets start with this. It will take pipeline input from an object (tested with `Import-CSV`) and then simulate output of `Format-List`. While it is outputing using `Write-Host` if the property being processed matches the `$ColouredProperty` then apply the foreground colour defined by `$colour`.

This currently only works if you need to colour one column but I could see this taking a hashtable input for it conditional formatting as well.

Let me know if we are on the right track.

## Conditional Colouring

You could easily make the colouring conditional base on criteria if you change the if statement and add another clause

```powershell
If($_ -eq $ColouredProperty -and $singleObject.$_ -match "\d")
```

It makes the function less transferable but it would work. I used that to highlight all file names with numbers in them.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -filter *.txt | Select Name,Length,Directory | Write-HostColoured -ColouredProperty Name
```

[image]

Comment: I think so. I'm still new to powershell but I was interested in coloring the output if it matched a certain string. If it wasn't too complex.

Comment: @Aaron. Figured that would be the direction you were going. That will take a _little_ more effort but I think we can do it (was already turning the wheel inside my head about it. ). Does the column name need to be highlighted?

Comment: If it's too difficult, no. But some values I get are like.... "Account locked?: True/False"..so the reason I would like to have True or False colored is so its easier to spot.

Comment: @Aaron would you prefer the colouring to only be conditional? Or do you want to colour the row anyway? or both?

Comment: Depends how difficult it would be. I'd like to learn both to see how it works, but I might stick with the output being colored in the end.

Comment: Doing _one_ thing is easy.

Comment: If just the output is easy then I'd say start there.

Comment: I will attempt but it looks overly more complex for what I know.